# Automated way to prevent ggplot hexbin from cutting geoms off axes

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a slightly different question from an earlier post([ggplot hexbin shows different number of hexagons in plot versus data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903657/ggplot-hexbin-shows-different-number-of-hexagons-in-plot-versus-data-frame)).

I am using hexbin() to bin data into hexagon objects, and ggplot() to plot the results. I notice that, sometimes, the hexagons on the edge of the plot are cut in half. Below is an example.

```
library(hexbin)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100), D=rnorm(100), E=rnorm(100))
maxVal = max(abs(data))
maxRange = c(-1*maxVal, maxVal)

x = data[,c("A")]
y = data[,c("E")]
h <- hexbin(x=x, y=y, xbins=5, shape=1, IDs=TRUE, xbnds=maxRange, ybnds=maxRange)
hexdf <- data.frame (hcell2xy (h),  hexID = h@cell, counts = h@count)
ggplot(hexdf, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = counts, hexID = hexID)) + 
  geom_hex(stat = "identity") + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2]), ylim = c(maxRange[1], maxRange[2]))
```

This creates a graphic where one hexagon is cut off at the top and one hexagon is cut off at the bottom:

[image]

Another approach I can try is to hard-code a value (here 1.5) to be added to the limits of the x and y axis. Doing so does seem to solve the problem in that no hexagons are cut off anymore.

```
ggplot(hexdf, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = counts, hexID = hexID)) + 
  geom_hex(stat = "identity") + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = maxRange * 1.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = maxRange * 1.5)
```

[image]

However, even though the second approach solves the problem in this instance, the value of 1.5 is arbitrary. I am trying to automate this process for a variety of data and variety of bin sizes and hexagon sizes that could be used. Is there a solution to keeping all hexagons fully visible in the plot without having to hard-code an arbitrary value that may be too large or too small for certain instances?

Comment: Just edited the answer to include the possibility to manually set the number of bins instead of the binwidth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that you can skip the computation of `hexbin`, and let ggplot do the job.

Then, if you prefer to **manually set the width of the bins** you can set the `binwidth` and modify the limits:

```
  bwd = 1
  ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_hex(binwidth = bwd)      + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(min(x) - bwd, max(x) + bwd), 
                    ylim = c(min(y) - bwd, max(y) + bwd), 
                    expand = T)   +
    geom_point(color = "red")     +
    theme_bw()
```

this way, hexagons should never be truncated (though you may end up with some "empty" space.

Result with `bwd = 1`:

[image]

Result with `bwd = 3`:

[image]

If instead **you prefer to programmatically set the number of the bins**, you can use:

```
  nbins_x <- 4
  nbins_y <- 6

  range_x <- range(data$A, na.rm  = T)
  range_y <- range(data$E, na.rm  = T)
  bwd_x   <- (range_x[2] - range_x[1])/nbins_x
  bwd_y   <- (range_y[2] - range_y[1])/nbins_y

  ggplot(data, aes(x = A, y = E)) + 
    geom_hex(bins = c(nbins_x,nbins_y)) + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(range_x[1] - bwd_x, range_x[2] + bwd_x),
                    ylim = c(range_y[1] - bwd_y, range_y[2] + bwd_y), 
                    expand = T) +
    geom_point(color = "red")+
    theme_bw()
```

[image]